# Why is modernizr not appending my html class?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I'm trying to get [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com) running on my site. I have added a `no-js` class to the my `<html>` element and have added the full, development script before my closing `</head>` tag.

For some reason, my `no-js` tag is not being appended.

I have checked in the script and the CSS classes bit is definitely there.

What else could this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience, the classes won't appear in View Source, but extensions such as Firebug (Firefox Add-on) will show them. If they don't appear, it usually is a linking issue with your `src` attribute.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it. It makes sense really, View Source is showing the html doc before the javascript has taken effect, whereas the element inspector for instance is live.

Comment: JavaScript is client-side, which means View Source won't show the result, it will show what you've coded.